# aws s3 upload files faster with sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload multiple files to AWS S3. It seems like it's really small as I am trying to upload 20k files.

I am using AWS SDK... Is there any good way of achieving this in a really fast way ? I don't want to use CLI for this.

Comment: Amazon S3 API calls only allow uploading a single object. However, you can multi-thread or run processes in parallel to upload multiple files via multiple API calls.

Answer (score 1):

Read this Amazon S3 doc:

[Bucket restrictions and limitations - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/BucketRestrictions.html)

There are no limits to the number of objects an Amazon S3 bucket can store. Therefore your 20K objects are fine. Now to address your question on how to do this with the AWS SDK. I will answer this question in terms of Java.

Explore this example to learn how to work with S3 Batch Operations using the AWS SDK for Java

[Github: S3 Batch Operations examples using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-s3-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/batch-ops-examples-java.md)